# SQL DATABASE USING VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, permissions, sql-server-2008, database

I have a very simple classic asp site on a Windows 2008 Server with an IIS 7.5 that connects to an Sql database on a Sql 2008 r2.

the site works perfectly when accessing it both locally from the server and from WWW.

Recently I've decided to start using VPN on my server so the site will not be available to the public internet.

I don't know why, but the page that needs to show the data from the database rich TIME OUT when accessing it using VPN from WINDOWS PCS. When i try to view the page from my Google Nexus 5 (VPN-L2TP) everything is perfect (on the same network of course..).
I've tried everything including disabling windows firewall. I've tried using Windows 8, 8.1, XP, 7. NOTHING. I've tried connecting with different protocols including PPTP, L2TP, SSTP, but NOTHING.

It's more than a week that i'm working on it.

I really need your help.

Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: Anyone?????????

Comment: 1. Are SQL Server and IIS on the same server or different servers? 2. How are you connecting to SQL Server within ASP (IP Address?)?  3. Has using VPN on your server changed the IP address?

Comment: 1. Yes, they both on the same server. 2. Here is my connection string: oCall.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=***\sqlexpress;Database=***;Uid=***; Pwd=***;". As I was saying if I connect to the site using HTTP, everything works. 3. Didn't get that. Could you be more precise?